# many to many select list data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to list the data with linq by combining the tables shown in the picture

[image: look at the photo]

expected result

[image: Result]

```
 using (CrmContext db = new Models.CrmContext())
            {
                _result = (from ct in db.CustomerDefination
                           join authorizedin db.authorized
                                    on ct.customerId equals authorized.authorized
                           join authorizedDefination in db.authorizedDefination 
                                    on authorized.authorizedId equals authorizedDefination .authorizedId
                           select new
                           {
                          ///I want to list the authorities belonging to 
 the customer

                           }).ToList();
            }
```

There may be more than one authoritative definition of a customer. How can I do this in the LINQ query?

Comment: Kindly translate to English the above words. what do you want to do? and what is your expected result?

Comment: I have edit.... there may be more than one authoritative definition of a customer. How can I do this in the linq query

Comment: If you already have a EF context, then please post the needed source classes as text and not as pictures. Also strip down those classes to only include the properties that are currently needed for your question. For the result than also write down a class with pseudo properties like `class Result { public int SourceOne.PropertyA { get; set; } }`. That would make it much easier to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent WAY too much time doing your job, @IbrahimALPSOY:

- Google Translating the turkish database screenshot,
- Understanding which table holds what data using more Google Translate,
- Understanding the expected result - which fields come from which tables,
- Writing sample classes to represent the database,
- Generating sample data for testing.

I wasted 30+ minutes *before even starting to write a query*. Next time I won't. Next time, you prepare your question such that, all other people could just copy your code and try queries right away.

### This is the preparation:

```
class Authorisation
{
    public int AuthorisationId; // yetkiliid
    public int AccessId; // unvanid
    public string AuthoriserName;
}
class Access
{
    public int AccessId; // unvanid
    public string AccessName;
}
class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId; // musterid
    public string CustomerName;
}
class Event
{
    public int CustomerId;
    public int AuthorisationId;
}

void Main()
{
    var Customers = new[] {
        new Customer() { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "Anne" },
        new Customer() { CustomerId = 2, CustomerName = "Barbara" },
    };
    var Accesses = new[] {
        new Access() { AccessId = 1, AccessName = "Read" },
        new Access() { AccessId = 2, AccessName = "Write" },
    };
    var Authorisations = new[] {
        new Authorisation() { AuthorisationId = 1, AuthoriserName = "The boss", AccessId = 1 }, // The boss can give read rights
        new Authorisation() { AuthorisationId = 2, AuthoriserName = "The boss", AccessId = 2 }, // The boss can give write rights
        new Authorisation() { AuthorisationId = 3, AuthoriserName = "A rookie", AccessId = 1 }, // A new employee can only give read rights
    };
    var Events = new[] {
        new Event() { CustomerId = 1, AuthorisationId = 3 }, // A rookie let Anne read
        new Event() { CustomerId = 1, AuthorisationId = 2 }, // While the boss let Anne write and scolded rookie
        new Event() { CustomerId = 2, AuthorisationId = 1 }, // The boss thinks Barbara can't be trusted with write
    };
}
```

I used this code instead of yours, because yours:

- doesn't compile,
- is illegible,
- is badly formatted,
- skips a table you've shown on your screenshot,
- contains references to contexts only you have access to.

### And here are the results:

Your query becomes feasible if you start with the table with non-unique keys:

```
from e in Events
    join c in Customers      on e.CustomerId      equals c.CustomerId
    join a in Authorisations on e.AuthorisationId equals a.AuthorisationId
    join s in Accesses       on a.AccessId        equals s.AccessId
select new
{
    e.CustomerId,
    e.AuthorisationId,
    c.CustomerName,
    a.AuthoriserName,
    s.AccessName
}
```

### If this is not what you needed, modify my "preparation" to fit your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time. I am grateful to you.

Comment: Sorry I "yelled". Please make it easier for others to answer and I will gladly answer all questions you ever post.

Comment: What did you mean when you said "There may be more than one authoritative definition of a customer"? That the CustomerId may appear several times in Events table (lower right on the screenshot)?

Comment: You're right. no problem. I will write clearer and clearer on my questions from now on. and I will do it for you =) thank you again @ensisNoctis

Comment: Ok, thanks. But did you answer solve your problem, or is it off?

Comment: You gave me the answer in a very clear way. problem solved. very well thank you very much